# Django: why does annotate add items to my queryset?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

I'm struggling to do something simple.
I have `Item` objects, and users can mark them favorites.
Since these items do not belong to user, I decided to use a ManyToMany between `User` and `Item` to record the favorite relationship. If the user is in `favoriters` item field, it means the user favorited it.

Then, when I retrieve objects for a specific user, I want to annotate each item to specify if it's favorited by the user. I made the `add_is_favorite_for()` method for this.

Here is the (simplified) code:

```py
class ItemQuerySet(query.QuerySet):
    def add_is_favorite_for(self, user):
        """add a boolean to know if the item is favorited by the given user"""
        condition = Q(favoriters=user)
        return self.annotate(is_favorite=ExpressionWrapper(condition, output_field=BooleanField()))

class Item(models.Model):
    objects = Manager.from_queryset(ItemQuerySet)()

    favoriters = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, blank=True)
```

This does not work as expected, it seems Django adds an item for **every** user that favorited the item. It leads to crazy things like:

```py
Item.objects.count() # 10
Item.objects.add_is_favorite_for(some_user).count() # 16 -> how the hell an annotation can return more results than initial queryset?
```

I'm missing something here...

Comment: The filter used in your annotation `favoriters=user` translates to a join at the SQL level which is why each Item will be repeated for every user that favourited it. It's possible that just adding `distinct()` to the query might fix the issue, otherwise the annotation can be changed to prevent this from happening

Comment: @IainShelvington `distinct()` does not work as expected, but can you elaborate about how changing the annotation itself to prevent this from happening? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the condition in the annotation to use a subquery, get all Items that the user has favourited and then test to see if the Item's id is in the subquery.

This should remove your issue with duplication:

```py
def add_is_favorite_for(self, user):
    return self.annotate(is_favorite=ExpressionWrapper(
        Q(id__in=Item.objects.filter(favoriters=user).values('id')),
        output_field=BooleanField()
    ))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works! I'm curious is this is the recommended way to do it or more like a workaround? I can't find official doc about this use case.